# ROute vom AWS to Azure website without changing the domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

I have a domain on aws like [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) but I installed my blog in a docker container in Azure and get a new automatic domain for that like myblog.azure.com.

So I want that my subdomain blog.domain.com route to myblog.azure.com without that the user will see the myblog.azure.com, they should see the blog.domain.com.

Is that possible?

I set up a A Type Routing with Alias to an S3 and redirect the S3 Bucket to my given Azure Domain. It works but sadly the URL will change with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overcomplicating this. You just need to setup a CNAME record in your DNS provider to point blog.domain.com to myblog.azure.com